# C Shell - How to check if argument starts with '-' character?

Tags: csh

I am new to csh and trying to check if argument starts with '-'. I've tried following:

```
if (`echo $var | awk '{print substr($var,0,1)}'` == '-') then
```

When running  script with argument 's', I get

```
if: Expression syntax
```

When running script with argument '-s', I get

```
if: Missing file name
```

I also tried

```
if ($var =~ -*) then
```

When running a script with argument '-s', I get

```
if: Missing file name
```

's' argument stays silent and does not get inside of if

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ("$var" =~ -*) then
```

has solved the problem for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @G.Samaras Why is this no answer to the question?

Comment: This should me a comment in my opinion, because it lacks explanation.